# How to optimize hibernate queries?

Tags: java, spring, postgresql, hibernate, query-performance

I am new to performance diagnostics and optimization. There is Spring based web app that uses hibernate + EhCache + HikariCP that backed by PostgreSQL. I am running SpringJUnit4ClassRunner tests together with 
`JProfiler` as the main tool for measuring and optimizing individual hibernate queries. The goal is to spot and fix mapping / fetching anti-patterns that lead to excessive query execution times.
The given scenario tests EhCache utilization and query execution times. As I understand the JDBC Hot Sports shows:

1. Six queries that each select 500 `Address` entities runs 5% of all time.

   ```
   106 ms - 1 evt. 
   SELECT address0_.address_id  AS address_1_1_, 
          address0_.address     AS address2_1_, 
          address0_.address2    AS address3_1_, 
          address0_.city_id     AS city_id8_1_, 
          address0_.district    AS district4_1_, 
          address0_.last_update AS last_upd5_1_, 
          address0_.phone       AS phone6_1_, 
          address0_.postal_code AS postal_c7_1_ 
   FROM   dvdrental.PUBLIC.address address0_ limit ?
   ```

   and

   ```
   30,161 micros - 6 evt. 
   SELECT     city0_.city_id        AS city_id1_3_0_, 
              city0_.city           AS city2_3_0_, 
              city0_.country_id     AS country_4_3_0_, 
              city0_.last_update    AS last_upd3_3_0_, 
              country1_.country_id  AS country_1_4_1_, 
              country1_.country     AS country2_4_1_, 
              country1_.last_update AS last_upd3_4_1_ 
   FROM       dvdrental.PUBLIC.city city0_ 
   inner join dvdrental.PUBLIC.country country1_ 
   ON         city0_.country_id=country1_.country_id 
   WHERE      city0_.city_id=?
   ```
2. The `City` entity is being retrieved 2,910 times (partially from EhCache?)

3,657 ms - 2,910 evt. 
    SELECT     city0_.city_id        AS city_id1_3_0_, 
               city0_.city           AS city2_3_0_, 
               city0_.country_id     AS country_4_3_0_, 
               city0_.last_update    AS last_upd3_3_0_, 
               country1_.country_id  AS country_1_4_1_, 
               country1_.country     AS country2_4_1_, 
               country1_.last_update AS last_upd3_4_1_ 
    FROM       dvdrental.PUBLIC.city city0_ 
    inner join dvdrental.PUBLIC.country country1_ 
    ON         city0_.country_id=country1_.country_id 
    WHERE      city0_.city_id=?

3. The `Store` why not country??? is being retrieved 3,000 times. (partially from EhCache?)

   5,660 ms - 3,000 evt. 
   SELECT          store0_.store_id          AS store_id1_12_13_, 
                   /* many more fields */
                   staff13_.username         AS usernam10_11_12_ 
   FROM            dvdrental.PUBLIC.store store0_ 
   inner join      dvdrental.PUBLIC.staff staff1_ 
   ON              store0_.manager_staff_id=staff1_.staff_id 
   left outer join dvdrental.PUBLIC.address address2_ 
   ON              staff1_.address_id=address2_.address_id 
   left outer join dvdrental.PUBLIC.city city3_ 
   ON              address2_.city_id=city3_.city_id 
   left outer join dvdrental.PUBLIC.country country4_ 
   ON              city3_.country_id=country4_.country_id 
   left outer join dvdrental.PUBLIC.payment payment5_ 
   ON              staff1_.staff_id=payment5_.staff_id 
   left outer join dvdrental.PUBLIC.customer customer6_ 
   ON              payment5_.customer_id=customer6_.customer_id 
   left outer join dvdrental.PUBLIC.address address7_ 
   ON              customer6_.address_id=address7_.address_id 
   left outer join dvdrental.PUBLIC.rental rental8_ 
   ON              payment5_.rental_id=rental8_.rental_id 
   left outer join dvdrental.PUBLIC.customer customer9_ 
   ON              rental8_.customer_id=customer9_.customer_id 
   left outer join dvdrental.PUBLIC.inventory inventory10_ 
   ON              rental8_.inventory_id=inventory10_.inventory_id 
   left outer join dvdrental.PUBLIC.film film11_ 
   ON              inventory10_.film_id=film11_.film_id 
   left outer join dvdrental.PUBLIC.LANGUAGE language12_ 
   ON              film11_.language_id=language12_.language_id 
   left outer join dvdrental.PUBLIC.staff staff13_ 
   ON              rental8_.staff_id=staff13_.staff_id 
   WHERE           store0_.address_id=?

**Console:**

```
JProfiler> Protocol version 50
JProfiler> Using JVMTI
JProfiler> JVMTI version 1.1 detected.
JProfiler> 64-bit library
JProfiler> Instrumenting native methods.
JProfiler> Can retransform classes.
JProfiler> Can retransform any class.
JProfiler> Native library initialized
JProfiler> VM initialized
JProfiler> Waiting for a connection from the JProfiler GUI ...
JProfiler> Using dynamic instrumentation
JProfiler> Time measurement: elapsed time
JProfiler> CPU profiling enabled
[timestamp] org.hibernate.jpa.internal.util.LogHelper logPersistenceUnitInformation
INFO: HHH000204: Processing PersistenceUnitInfo [
    name: default
    ...]
[timestamp] org.hibernate.Version logVersion
INFO: HHH000412: Hibernate Core {4.3.11.Final}
[timestamp] org.hibernate.cfg.Environment <clinit>
INFO: HHH000206: hibernate.properties not found
[timestamp] org.hibernate.cfg.Environment buildBytecodeProvider
INFO: HHH000021: Bytecode provider name : javassist
[timestamp] org.hibernate.annotations.common.reflection.java.JavaReflectionManager <clinit>
INFO: HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations {4.0.5.Final}
[timestamp] org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect <init>
INFO: HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect
[timestamp] org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.LobCreatorBuilder useContextualLobCreation
INFO: HHH000424: Disabling contextual LOB creation as createClob() method threw error : java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
[timestamp] org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.ASTQueryTranslatorFactory <init>
INFO: HHH000397: Using ASTQueryTranslatorFactory
[timestamp] org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory buildSettings
WARN: Unrecognized value for "hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto": none
[timestamp] org.hibernate.cache.spi.UpdateTimestampsCache <init>
INFO: HHH000250: Starting update timestamps cache at region: org.hibernate.cache.spi.UpdateTimestampsCache
[timestamp] org.hibernate.cache.ehcache.AbstractEhcacheRegionFactory getCache
WARN: HHH020003: Could not find a specific ehcache configuration for cache named [org.hibernate.cache.spi.UpdateTimestampsCache]; using defaults.
[timestamp] org.hibernate.cache.internal.StandardQueryCache <init>
INFO: HHH000248: Starting query cache at region: org.hibernate.cache.internal.StandardQueryCache
[timestamp] org.hibernate.cache.ehcache.AbstractEhcacheRegionFactory getCache
WARN: HHH020003: Could not find a specific ehcache configuration for cache named [org.hibernate.cache.internal.StandardQueryCache]; using defaults.
[timestamp] org.hibernate.validator.internal.util.Version <clinit>
INFO: HV000001: Hibernate Validator 5.2.2.Final
[timestamp] org.hibernate.cache.ehcache.AbstractEhcacheRegionFactory getCache
WARN: HHH020003: Could not find a specific ehcache configuration for cache named [com.hibernate.query.performance.persistence.model.Address]; using defaults.
[timestamp] org.hibernate.cache.ehcache.AbstractEhcacheRegionFactory getCache
WARN: HHH020003: Could not find a specific ehcache configuration for cache named [customer]; using defaults.
[timestamp] org.hibernate.cache.ehcache.AbstractEhcacheRegionFactory getCache
WARN: HHH020003: Could not find a specific ehcache configuration for cache named [staff]; using defaults.
[timestamp] org.hibernate.cache.ehcache.AbstractEhcacheRegionFactory getCache
WARN: HHH020003: Could not find a specific ehcache configuration for cache named [language]; using defaults.
[timestamp] org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect <init>
INFO: HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect
[timestamp] org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.LobCreatorBuilder useContextualLobCreation
INFO: HHH000424: Disabling contextual LOB creation as createClob() method threw error : java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
[timestamp] org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.TransactionFactoryInitiator initiateService
INFO: HHH000399: Using default transaction strategy (direct JDBC transactions)
[timestamp] org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.ASTQueryTranslatorFactory <init>
INFO: HHH000397: Using ASTQueryTranslatorFactory
[timestamp] org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory buildSettings
WARN: Unrecognized value for "hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto": none
[timestamp] org.hibernate.cache.spi.UpdateTimestampsCache <init>
INFO: HHH000250: Starting update timestamps cache at region: org.hibernate.cache.spi.UpdateTimestampsCache
[timestamp] org.hibernate.cache.ehcache.AbstractEhcacheRegionFactory getCache
WARN: HHH020003: Could not find a specific ehcache configuration for cache named [org.hibernate.cache.spi.UpdateTimestampsCache]; using defaults.
[timestamp] org.hibernate.cache.internal.StandardQueryCache <init>
INFO: HHH000248: Starting query cache at region: org.hibernate.cache.internal.StandardQueryCache
[timestamp] org.hibernate.cache.ehcache.AbstractEhcacheRegionFactory getCache
WARN: HHH020003: Could not find a specific ehcache configuration for cache named [org.hibernate.cache.internal.StandardQueryCache]; using defaults.
[timestamp] org.hibernate.cache.ehcache.AbstractEhcacheRegionFactory getCache
WARN: HHH020003: Could not find a specific ehcache configuration for cache named [com.hibernate.query.performance.persistence.model.Address]; using defaults.
[timestamp] org.hibernate.cache.ehcache.AbstractEhcacheRegionFactory getCache
WARN: HHH020003: Could not find a specific ehcache configuration for cache named [customer]; using defaults.
[timestamp] org.hibernate.cache.ehcache.AbstractEhcacheRegionFactory getCache
WARN: HHH020003: Could not find a specific ehcache configuration for cache named [staff]; using defaults.
[timestamp] org.hibernate.cache.ehcache.AbstractEhcacheRegionFactory getCache
WARN: HHH020003: Could not find a specific ehcache configuration for cache named [language]; using defaults.
[timestamp][main] ERROR - Starting QueryTimeWithEHCacheTest

[timestamp] org.hibernate.cache.internal.StandardQueryCache <init>
INFO: HHH000248: Starting query cache at region: address
[timestamp] org.hibernate.cache.ehcache.AbstractEhcacheRegionFactory getCache
WARN: HHH020003: Could not find a specific ehcache configuration for cache named [address]; using defaults.
[timestamp] org.hibernate.engine.internal.StatisticalLoggingSessionEventListener end
INFO: Session Metrics {
    30693123 nanoseconds spent acquiring 1 JDBC connections;
    0 nanoseconds spent releasing 0 JDBC connections;
    0 nanoseconds spent preparing 0 JDBC statements;
    0 nanoseconds spent executing 0 JDBC statements;
    0 nanoseconds spent executing 0 JDBC batches;
    0 nanoseconds spent performing 0 L2C puts;
    0 nanoseconds spent performing 0 L2C hits;
    0 nanoseconds spent performing 0 L2C misses;
    0 nanoseconds spent executing 0 flushes (flushing a total of 0 entities and 0 collections);
    0 nanoseconds spent executing 0 partial-flushes (flushing a total of 0 entities and 0 collections)
}
[timestamp][main] ERROR - Transaction #init took 4078 ms

[timestamp] org.hibernate.engine.internal.StatisticalLoggingSessionEventListener end
INFO: Session Metrics {
    26051941 nanoseconds spent acquiring 1 JDBC connections;
    0 nanoseconds spent releasing 0 JDBC connections;
    215664108 nanoseconds spent preparing 987 JDBC statements;
    2115057343 nanoseconds spent executing 987 JDBC statements;
    0 nanoseconds spent executing 0 JDBC batches;
    51375385 nanoseconds spent performing 501 L2C puts;
    0 nanoseconds spent performing 0 L2C hits;
    91260 nanoseconds spent performing 1 L2C misses;
    86065349 nanoseconds spent executing 1 flushes (flushing a total of 1093 entities and 1093 collections);
    0 nanoseconds spent executing 0 partial-flushes (flushing a total of 0 entities and 0 collections)
}
[timestamp] org.hibernate.engine.internal.StatisticalLoggingSessionEventListener end
[timestamp][main] ERROR - Transaction #0 took 2469 ms

INFO: Session Metrics {
    24727694 nanoseconds spent acquiring 1 JDBC connections;
    0 nanoseconds spent releasing 0 JDBC connections;
    0 nanoseconds spent preparing 0 JDBC statements;
    0 nanoseconds spent executing 0 JDBC statements;
    0 nanoseconds spent executing 0 JDBC batches;
    0 nanoseconds spent performing 0 L2C puts;
    0 nanoseconds spent performing 0 L2C hits;
    0 nanoseconds spent performing 0 L2C misses;
    0 nanoseconds spent executing 0 flushes (flushing a total of 0 entities and 0 collections);
    0 nanoseconds spent executing 0 partial-flushes (flushing a total of 0 entities and 0 collections)
}
[timestamp] org.hibernate.engine.internal.StatisticalLoggingSessionEventListener end
INFO: Session Metrics {
    23262410 nanoseconds spent acquiring 1 JDBC connections;
    0 nanoseconds spent releasing 0 JDBC connections;
    157571091 nanoseconds spent preparing 986 JDBC statements;
    1545907919 nanoseconds spent executing 986 JDBC statements;
    0 nanoseconds spent executing 0 JDBC batches;
    0 nanoseconds spent performing 0 L2C puts;
    13736681 nanoseconds spent performing 501 L2C hits;
    10272 nanoseconds spent performing 1 L2C misses;
    34459640 nanoseconds spent executing 1 flushes (flushing a total of 1093 entities and 1093 collections);
    0 nanoseconds spent executing 0 partial-flushes (flushing a total of 0 entities and 0 collections)
}
[timestamp] org.hibernate.engine.internal.StatisticalLoggingSessionEventListener end
INFO: Session Metrics {
    25324237 nanoseconds spent acquiring 1 JDBC connections;
    0 nanoseconds spent releasing 0 JDBC connections;
    0 nanoseconds spent preparing 0 JDBC statements;
    0 nanoseconds spent executing 0 JDBC statements;
    0 nanoseconds spent executing 0 JDBC batches;
    0 nanoseconds spent performing 0 L2C puts;
    0 nanoseconds spent performing 0 L2C hits;
    0 nanoseconds spent performing 0 L2C misses;
    0 nanoseconds spent executing 0 flushes (flushing a total of 0 entities and 0 collections);
    0 nanoseconds spent executing 0 partial-flushes (flushing a total of 0 entities and 0 collections)
}
[timestamp] org.hibernate.engine.internal.StatisticalLoggingSessionEventListener end
INFO: Session Metrics {
    24041077 nanoseconds spent acquiring 1 JDBC connections;
    0 nanoseconds spent releasing 0 JDBC connections;
    155411292 nanoseconds spent preparing 986 JDBC statements;
    1739510225 nanoseconds spent executing 986 JDBC statements;
    0 nanoseconds spent executing 0 JDBC batches;
    0 nanoseconds spent performing 0 L2C puts;
    5709031 nanoseconds spent performing 501 L2C hits;
    11852 nanoseconds spent performing 1 L2C misses;
    27861718 nanoseconds spent executing 1 flushes (flushing a total of 1093 entities and 1093 collections);
    0 nanoseconds spent executing 0 partial-flushes (flushing a total of 0 entities and 0 collections)
}
[timestamp][main] ERROR - Transaction #1 took 2610 ms

[timestamp] org.hibernate.engine.internal.StatisticalLoggingSessionEventListener end
INFO: Session Metrics {
    23408584 nanoseconds spent acquiring 1 JDBC connections;
    0 nanoseconds spent releasing 0 JDBC connections;
    0 nanoseconds spent preparing 0 JDBC statements;
    0 nanoseconds spent executing 0 JDBC statements;
    0 nanoseconds spent executing 0 JDBC batches;
    0 nanoseconds spent performing 0 L2C puts;
    0 nanoseconds spent performing 0 L2C hits;
    0 nanoseconds spent performing 0 L2C misses;
    0 nanoseconds spent executing 0 flushes (flushing a total of 0 entities and 0 collections);
    0 nanoseconds spent executing 0 partial-flushes (flushing a total of 0 entities and 0 collections)
}
[timestamp][main] ERROR - Transaction #2 took 2288 ms

[timestamp] org.hibernate.engine.internal.StatisticalLoggingSessionEventListener end
INFO: Session Metrics {
    23451250 nanoseconds spent acquiring 1 JDBC connections;
    0 nanoseconds spent releasing 0 JDBC connections;
    145723202 nanoseconds spent preparing 986 JDBC statements;
    1464820331 nanoseconds spent executing 986 JDBC statements;
    0 nanoseconds spent executing 0 JDBC batches;
    0 nanoseconds spent performing 0 L2C puts;
    5532445 nanoseconds spent performing 501 L2C hits;
    3160 nanoseconds spent performing 1 L2C misses;
    31112679 nanoseconds spent executing 1 flushes (flushing a total of 1093 entities and 1093 collections);
    0 nanoseconds spent executing 0 partial-flushes (flushing a total of 0 entities and 0 collections)
}
[timestamp] org.hibernate.engine.internal.StatisticalLoggingSessionEventListener end
INFO: Session Metrics {
    26841273 nanoseconds spent acquiring 1 JDBC connections;
    0 nanoseconds spent releasing 0 JDBC connections;
    0 nanoseconds spent preparing 0 JDBC statements;
    0 nanoseconds spent executing 0 JDBC statements;
    0 nanoseconds spent executing 0 JDBC batches;
    0 nanoseconds spent performing 0 L2C puts;
    0 nanoseconds spent performing 0 L2C hits;
    0 nanoseconds spent performing 0 L2C misses;
    0 nanoseconds spent executing 0 flushes (flushing a total of 0 entities and 0 collections);
    0 nanoseconds spent executing 0 partial-flushes (flushing a total of 0 entities and 0 collections)
}
[timestamp] org.hibernate.engine.internal.StatisticalLoggingSessionEventListener end
INFO: Session Metrics {
    25004237 nanoseconds spent acquiring 1 JDBC connections;
    0 nanoseconds spent releasing 0 JDBC connections;
    159031639 nanoseconds spent preparing 986 JDBC statements;
    1539390609 nanoseconds spent executing 986 JDBC statements;
    0 nanoseconds spent executing 0 JDBC batches;
    0 nanoseconds spent performing 0 L2C puts;
    5428922 nanoseconds spent performing 501 L2C hits;
    3161 nanoseconds spent performing 1 L2C misses;
    37890751 nanoseconds spent executing 1 flushes (flushing a total of 1093 entities and 1093 collections);
    0 nanoseconds spent executing 0 partial-flushes (flushing a total of 0 entities and 0 collections)
}
[timestamp][main] ERROR - Transaction #3 took 2428 ms

[timestamp] org.hibernate.engine.internal.StatisticalLoggingSessionEventListener end
INFO: Session Metrics {
    24766806 nanoseconds spent acquiring 1 JDBC connections;
    0 nanoseconds spent releasing 0 JDBC connections;
    0 nanoseconds spent preparing 0 JDBC statements;
    0 nanoseconds spent executing 0 JDBC statements;
    0 nanoseconds spent executing 0 JDBC batches;
    0 nanoseconds spent performing 0 L2C puts;
    0 nanoseconds spent performing 0 L2C hits;
    0 nanoseconds spent performing 0 L2C misses;
    0 nanoseconds spent executing 0 flushes (flushing a total of 0 entities and 0 collections);
    0 nanoseconds spent executing 0 partial-flushes (flushing a total of 0 entities and 0 collections)
}
[timestamp] org.hibernate.engine.internal.StatisticalLoggingSessionEventListener end
INFO: Session Metrics {
    26597126 nanoseconds spent acquiring 1 JDBC connections;
    0 nanoseconds spent releasing 0 JDBC connections;
    156316396 nanoseconds spent preparing 986 JDBC statements;
    1703458093 nanoseconds spent executing 986 JDBC statements;
    0 nanoseconds spent executing 0 JDBC batches;
    0 nanoseconds spent performing 0 L2C puts;
    4467764 nanoseconds spent performing 501 L2C hits;
    2765 nanoseconds spent performing 1 L2C misses;
    29417865 nanoseconds spent executing 1 flushes (flushing a total of 1093 entities and 1093 collections);
    0 nanoseconds spent executing 0 partial-flushes (flushing a total of 0 entities and 0 collections)
}
[timestamp][main] ERROR - Transaction #4 took 2543 ms

JProfiler> Keeping VM alive until frontend disconnects.
```

**Test**

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(classes = {ApplicationTestConfig.class, CachingConfig.class }, loader = AnnotationConfigContextLoader.class)
@Transactional(transactionManager = "hibernateTransactionManager")
public class QueryTimeWithEHCacheTest extends AbstractTransactionalJUnit4SpringContextTests {

    private static final org.apache.logging.log4j.Logger logger = LogManager.getRootLogger();

    @Autowired
    private SessionFactory sessionFactory;

    @Test
    public void testTransactionCaching(){
        logger.error("Starting QueryTimeWithEHCacheTest");
        long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
        Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();
        Query query = session.createQuery("from Address").setCacheable(true).setCacheRegion("address").setMaxResults(500);

        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        List<Address> entities = query.list();
        session.flush();
        TestTransaction.flagForCommit();
        TestTransaction.end();
        session.clear();
        session.close();
        long end = System.currentTimeMillis();
        logger.error("Transaction #init took " + (end - start) + " ms");

        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
            start = System.currentTimeMillis();
            TestTransaction.start();
            Session sessionNew =  sessionFactory.openSession();
            Query anotherQuery = sessionNew.createQuery("from Address").setMaxResults(500);
            anotherQuery.setCacheable(true).setCacheRegion("address");
            @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
            List<Address> addressrFromCache = anotherQuery.list();
            sessionNew.flush();
            TestTransaction.flagForCommit();
            TestTransaction.end();
            sessionNew.clear();
            sessionNew.close();
            end = System.currentTimeMillis();
            logger.error("Transaction #" + i  + " took " + (end - start) + " ms");
        }
    }
}
```

What can be improved regarding my optimization approach? Are there any obvious problems that slow down query execution? Is there a room for improving queries?

[image]